# Whats the best way to change the background color of collapse-accordion dynamically in react native

Tags: react-native

i have used accordion-collapse-react-native in my project .But i tried to change  each collapse color dynamically,which is  based on the Qr scanning. i failed to display the color for each collapse.can you help me out?

Comment: Please edit the question to show what you've tried, and show a specific roadblock you're running into with [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For more information, please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

You can change the background color by using `this.setState`

Set the initial background color in your constructor

```
this.state = {
    backgroundColor: randomHex()
}
```

in your render function change your style prop to:

```
[styles.container, {backgroundColor: this.state.backgroundColor}]
```

and onClick add

```
this.setState({backgroundColor: randomHex()});
```

Heres the full code

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
    import {
        AppRegistry,
        StyleSheet,
        Text,
        View,
        TouchableHighlight
    } from 'react-native';

    let randomHex = () => {
        let letters = '0123456789ABCDEF';
        let color = '#';
        for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++ ) {
            color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
        }
        return color;
    }

    export default class randomBackground extends Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props)

            this.onClick = this.onClick.bind(this);

            this.state = {
                backgroundColor: randomHex()
            };

        }
        onClick() {
            console.log('clicked ');
            this.setState({backgroundColor: randomHex()}); 
        }
        render() {
            return (
                <TouchableHighlight onPress={ this.onClick } style={[styles.container, {backgroundColor: this.state.backgroundColor}]}>
                    <View>
                        <Text style={styles.instructions}>
                            Tap to change the background
                        </Text>
                    </View>
                </TouchableHighlight>
            );
        }
    }
    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
        container: {
            flex: 1,
            justifyContent: 'center',
            alignItems: 'center',
            backgroundColor: randomHex()
        },
        instructions: {
            color: "white"
        }
    });
    AppRegistry.registerComponent('randomBackground', () => randomBackground);
```

Comment: thanks for your reply .But my requirement is different .i have two components,first component holds the API data and it passes the (color state) appropriate colors to second component according to the condition.Second component will displays the collapse header color based upon the first component color props. but it display only  one color at a time on the collapse header.

Comment: You need to customize the design then 
Step 1: once Api data receives u just pass that information to second Component while design time You just update the color that's enough

Comment: <Component2  state_value={this.state.Color}/> this is how i am paasing the state value to the component2.I'm passing the state value after checking all the conditions . and it's displays the one color at a time

Comment: sorry it's displays only one collapse header color at a time